# What is a good character length for a code when we need 1 million unique variations?

Tags: mysql, unique, records

I need a good trade off between readability (e.g. not too long) vs being long enough to create 1 million unique variations.

The code can use numbers and letters.

We need to provision 1 million unique voucher codes and I am designing the model.

It is probably inconsequential, but we will be using MySQL to stored the codes.

Comment: the best char length is 4 (an int) :p

Comment: You may slice and dice timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You use 26 Letters (latin alphabet eg. UPPERCASE only) + 10 digits (0,1,...,9) gives you 36 different choices of alphanumeric characters. Combination of 4 alphanumeric characters:

```
36 * 36 * 36 * 36 = 1679616
```

gives us 1679616 different combinations.

If You would add two extra characters it gives us:

```
36 * 36 * 36 * 36 * 36 * 36 = 2176782336
```

2176782336 possible voucher codes. Pick randomly one million from over 2 billions and store them in a table.

Comment: +1 This is true, but for security reasons pick at least 8 letters - thats still not to long, and 36 ^ 8 = 2821109907456. But yes, also 2176782336 is enough to have only 1000000 valid codes. Also be careful to not be mistaken with `0` and `O`.

Comment: This is far fewer than I had anticipated needing! Great. I may add more digits to give a sense of importance - e.g. a long code feels more special/valuable somehow.